efi-stub boot fails despite correct kernel args
Complete boot log:
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GP18.SATA], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)

My system once started up with saying no disk is available or whatever. I rebooted and it used the disk to boot Windows, but the manually added UEFI boot entry for archlinux disappeared. I tried to add it back through windows (a lot of pain, but should have been successfull). But now the entries print this, whether I want to run my vmlinuz-linux, or my lts backup, or include a backslash before it, or pass the root PARTUUID as UUID, or not include the initrd=\booster-linux-lts.img
passing splash changed nothing about the log output
I'm kind of desparate, because I have no USB and no easy acces to one, that could be used for a linux distro to chroot into my system from.

Unfortunately the message was totally unrelated to the issue, it was there even when the system worked.
The issue turns out to be that when using EFIBootEditor, you must select UTF-16 encoding for the Options/arguments passed to the kernel. It won't boot otherwise, because it won't be able to parse the parameters.
The only neccessary arguments for the kernel are root=PARTUUID=<sgdisk output> and initrd=\your-initramfs.img
Sgdisk can give you the partition unique GUID (as they call it in the output) using sgdisk64.exe --info=<your-root-partition-number> <disk-number>:, where disk-number is usually 0 and partitions are indexed from 1
